# How do I profile memory usage with pypy?

Tags: python, profiling, pypy

I've tried the following profilers, all of which are not compatible with pypy (5.8.0):

- pympler: fails on import as pypy does not support `__itemsize__`, and according to some google results it would not produce useful results anyways
- vmprof: outputs "Memory profiling is currently unsupported for PyPy. Running without memory statistics."
- objgraph: `most_common_types()` returns an empty list.

Is there any way of getting a list of types and the memory usage of their instances in pypy (equivalent to `objgraph.most_common_types()`)?

Comment: `objgraph.show_growth()` had worked for me in the past on PyPy. Same for `objgraph.show_backrefs([<list of objects>])`.